# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed when using docker +docker-compose+kafka+springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am ruuning docker compose on ec2 which is 4 containers. but getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper_container
    networks:
      - my_network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka_container
    hostname: kafka
    networks:
      - my_network
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://57.125.58.225:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  springboot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: imageone
    container_name: imageone_container
    networks:
      - my_network
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/fasmho
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9093

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: fasmho
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

application properties

```
server.port=9000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/fasmho
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.kaif.dockersringboot.entities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Postgres service has no matching networks as the app, so it will not be able to connect with it

```
networks:
  - my_network
```

Best practice would also include adding a depends_on for the database